# java.io.FileNotFoundException: sync/assets.lst

Tags: android, file, assets, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to use my assets as a "File" variable,
But when I'm doing:

> ```
>     Assets assets=null;
>     try {
>         assets = new Assets(getApplicationContext());
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     File modelsdir = null;
>     try {
>         modelsdir = new File(assets.syncAssets(),"sync/models");
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> ```

"modelsdir" returns null (or blank).
I get the next error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: sync/assets.lst
```

And I'm sure I have this file on "sync/assets.lst" and "assets/sync/assets.lst".

Can you help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have the folder `sync` with the file `assets.lst` in your `assets` folder in your Android project.

I don't recognize your method for accessing your asset files, but you might try this way:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
InputStream input = null;
try {
    input = assetManager.open("sync/assets.lst");
    //do some reading from the file
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try{
        if(input != null){ input.close(); }
    }catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

You can't have File objects from your assets, however you can have an AssetFileDescriptor

```
AssetFileDescriptor file = assetManager.openFd("sync/assets.lst");
//do some work with the descriptor
file.close();
```

More info:

[AssetFileDescriptor | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html)

[AssetManager | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)

Comment: file = assetManager.openFd("sync/assets.lst");
also returns
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: sync/assets.lst
And I'm sure I have the file in my project assets/sync.
What could I do?

Comment: And I need to retrieve file from Assets as File.
Is there a way I could do it? maybe moving the file outside of assets folder?

Comment: You can check if there file is there, by renaming the output apk to a zip file, extracting it, and checking its assets folder. About the File object, i don't know any way to convert it to File. Why do you need it as a File anyway?

Comment: I have a method of PocketSphinx libary that needs to get file from my app. Is there any way to use raw files in my app?
`modelsdir=new File(assetsdir,"models");
speechrecognizer = defaultSetup()
.setAcousticModel(new File(modelsdir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
.setDictionary(new File(modelsdir, "dict/cmu07a.dic"))
.getRecognizer();
`